# iframe submission nulls the request parameters for parent form

Tags: forms, jsp, iframe, submit, image-uploading

I am using hidden iframe in my jsp to upload image files. The code is as following :

```
  <form name="frm" method="POST" action="./servlet/newSubmit1">
      <div>
           Image:
          <input type="file" id="uploadImage" name="uploadImage" size="30" onchange="uploadFiles(); fileUpload(this.form,'./servlet/TempImageUploader','upload123')"/>
          <input type="hidden" id="UserName" value="TestValue"/>
      </div>
      <div id="upload123"></div>
      <ul>
          <li>  
               <input type="button" value="Upload" tabindex="6" onclick="uploadAttachedPhotos()"/>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </form>
```

As you can see in the code that onchange event of browse button "uploadFiles()" and "fileUpload" function is called. The **uploadFiles** function uses **DWR** to upload file to temp directory on server and preview it on jsp page, and the **fileUplaod** function creates a hidden iframe to call the servlet which maintains all the uploaded images in a map. I have some other data too on the page which can be updated by the user. For example here i have "UserName" field which can have name of the file.

The javascript function which creates hidden iframe is :

```
   function fileUpload(form, action_url, div_id) {
       // Create the iframe...
       var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
       iframe.setAttribute("id", "upload_iframe");
       iframe.setAttribute("name", "upload_iframe");
       iframe.setAttribute("width", "0");
       iframe.setAttribute("height", "0");
       iframe.setAttribute("border", "0");
       iframe.setAttribute("style", "width: 0; height: 0; border: none;");

       // Add to document...
       form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);
       window.frames['upload_iframe'].name = "upload_iframe";

       iframeId = document.getElementById("upload_iframe");

       // Add event...
       var eventHandler = function () {

            if (iframeId.detachEvent) iframeId.detachEvent("onload", eventHandler);
            else iframeId.removeEventListener("load", eventHandler, false);

           // Message from server...
           if (iframeId.contentDocument) {
               content = iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
           } else if (iframeId.contentWindow) {
               content = iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
           } else if (iframeId.document) {
               content = iframeId.document.body.innerHTML;
           }

           document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = content;

           // Del the iframe...
           setTimeout('iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)', 250);
       }

       if (iframeId.addEventListener) iframeId.addEventListener("load", eventHandler, true);
       if (iframeId.attachEvent) iframeId.attachEvent("onload", eventHandler);

       // Set properties of form...
       form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe");
       form.setAttribute("action", action_url);
       form.setAttribute("method", "post");
       form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
       form.setAttribute("encoding", "multipart/form-data");

       // Submit the form...
       document.forms[0].action = action_url;
       document.forms[0].submit();

       document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = "Uploading...";
 }
```

Now the question is why i am getting  `request.getParameter("UserName")` NULL on the parent form's action servlet, when i press the upload button ?

Thanks

Comment: Because you should be using `getPart()` instead on `multipart/form-data` requests. Duplicate of [How to upload files in JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

Comment: @BalusC thanks for the response. As my question is not duplicate and i am using DWR for file uploading, i edited my question. Sorry i didn't mentioned it earlier.

Comment: The way how you parse `multipart/form-data` requests in the servlet is **not** different.

Comment: @BalusC Oh Man! i am not having any problem regarding file uploading. File is uploaded successfully. But when i submit form, then the parameter is null.

Comment: OK, I give up. Good luck figuring the problem. You might want to re-read the linked dupe more carefully though.

Comment: I didn't find where you are setting the value of hidden parameter 'fileName' in your code.

Comment: @HardikMishra Pls don't get confused with that hidden field. It is set on page load, for your convenience i had set a default value.

Comment: Ok.. As Per BalusC 's comment. When you use "enctype="multipart/form-data" in you form tag, It will always give NULL when you use request.getParameter("fileName").

Comment: @HardikMishra You can see that in my main form there is no enctype.

Comment: @HardikMishra Here 'fileName' field was a bit confusing so i changed the name to 'UserName'

Comment: Since you have already uploaded the image, why don't you simply feed an hidden field and use it on the server side to grab the previously uploaded file?